# The operation has timed out on EF Core migration to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I am new to PostgreSQL and I would like to use it with Identity Server 4.
I am using next NuGet packages: IdentityServer4, IdentityServer4.EntityFramework and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

I am trying to make migration for Identity Server tables on PostgreSQL. I am modifying ConfigureServices in Startup.cs with:

```
string connectionString = "Server=192.168.1.108; Port=5432; Database=postgres; User Id=postgres;Password=mysecretpassword";
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
            options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString, action=>
                {
                    action.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly);
                });
        });
```

When I run Add-Migration command, I can see that VS prepares all migration information for me (I can see all the tables that I need), but when I run Update-Database command I get some weird error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 2.1.4-rtm-31024 initialized 'ConfigurationDbContext' using provider
>   'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options:
>   MigrationsAssembly=MangEx.Users  System.TimeoutException: The
>   operation has timed out.    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout) in
>   C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 703    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 555    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 414    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>   in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 270
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() in
>   C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 153    at
>   Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
>   in
>   C:\projects\EFCore.PG\src\EFCore.PG\Storage\Internal\NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.cs:line
>   216    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) The operation has timed out.

I am running PostgreSQL via Docker and it is active container, plus I am running pgAdmin4 as a Docker container and it is seeing PostgreSQL container.

I am probably missing something trivial, but as I said I am totally new to PostgreSQL so I can't pinpoint the cause of this error.

I would appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake. I have runned docker image of PostgreSQL without opening the port to outside world. When I runned that image with -p 5432:5432, I have managed to migrate Identity Server tables to the database.

Comment: I`m new in Npgsql & PostgreSQL . Im getting same error when I`m trying to migrate code first database & update command

Could you please help me